# How does .NET framework allocate memory for OutOfMemoryException?

Tags: c#, .net, out-of-memory

In C++ it's actually possible to throw an exception by value without allocating memory on a heap, so this situation makes sense. But in .NET framework `OutOfMemoryException` is a reference type, therefore it is allocated on a heap. 
How does .NET framework allocates memory for `OutOfMemoryException` when there is not enough memory to create a new object?

Comment: Excellent question. Maybe enough memory is reserved for just that situation.

Comment: Just to add to the other answers already here, bear in mind that OOM means that the block you requested can't be allocated. If you ask for 100Mb and the largest available block the runtime can find is only 99Mb, it will fail. But an OOM exception only needs a few bytes of memory. So just because your allocation failed it doesn't mean there is zero memory left. But of course it is likely that the runtime reserves some memory to cover itself in this situation

Comment: Your assumption about C++ is incorrect, by the way. Depending on the compiler, exceptions may well be allocated on the heap. The MS compiler does not, but in the Common C++ ABI, exceptions are allocated on the heap, except that there is a small preallocated emergency buffer that will be used instead if there's no space left on the heap.

Answer (score 164, accepted):

It is preallocated by the runtime. If you explore the heap of any managed process you'll find an instance of that exception.

Here are the preallocated exceptions of a Hello World app:

```
0:003> !dumpheap -stat -type Exception
Statistics:
      MT    Count    TotalSize Class Name
735f2920        1           84 System.ExecutionEngineException
735f28dc        1           84 System.StackOverflowException
735f2898        1           84 System.OutOfMemoryException
735f2744        1           84 System.Exception
735f2964        2          168 System.Threading.ThreadAbortException
```

Comment: But the [constructor of `OutOfMemoryException`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/outofmemoryexception.cs,5ad855b434264d4b,references) is called.

Comment: The runtime doesn't have to play by the same rules as your code. Another example is that if you throw `StackOverflowException` you can catch it, but if the runtime throws that exception you can't catch it (by default).

Comment: Much of the underlying mechanisms of the CLR are actually written in "C" and "C++". So, it's entirely possible that the object is "new'd in place" or the memory is otherwise manipulated.

Comment: @hvd What's the side effect? Does OOM give a stack trace? I would have though the rest of the information is fairly static?

Comment: @JamesBarrass Thanks for making me take a closer look, I now think there is none. :) Following Tim Schmelter's link to the source code, I just got the wrong impression, but the constructor is indeed only setting the exception's instance data to static values.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen I assume this preallocated instance is somehow shared between AppDomains? Because if OOM exception crosses AppDomain boundaries, it is serialized and deserialized (meaning more memory allocations).

Comment: @RX_DID_RX I haven't investigated appdomain crossing, but it occurs to me that if the runtime is still out of memory when it tries to do this (or e.g. when any finalizer runs) it will simply encounter the out-of-memory condition again and throw a "new" (still preallocated) OutOfMemoryException at that point.

Comment: What if two exceptions of those with the same type are required because two threads throw them at the same time?

Answer (score 42):

When an out-of-memory condition is encountered inside the runtime, it calls [ThrowOutOfMemory](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/utilcode/ex.cpp#L1688). This calls [Exception::GetOOMException](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/utilcode/ex.cpp#L41), which constructs the object on the stack and then copies it to a statically-allocated global instance, which is then thrown.

This is not the managed Exception, though, it a C++ exception declared in [ex.h](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/inc/ex.h). C++ Exceptions are converted to managed Exceptions in [clrex.cpp](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/vm/clrex.cpp), which contains code to specifically throw the preallocated *managed* OutOfMemoryException, which was originally allocated and constructed in [appdomain.cpp](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/vm/appdomain.cpp).

Note: Some of these source files are large and may hang your browser for several seconds while it loads the syntax highlighting.

The call sites that Tim Schmelter linked in a comment on the other answer aren't related to the runtime running out of memory and being unable to construct an object.